Some problems about the rotation index of Lissajous curve
This is a exercise(1.56) from Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces (Kristopher Tapp) , which asks the rotation index of the Lissajous curve $\gamma(t)=(\cos(mt),\sin(nt))$ where $m,n$ are positive integers and $t\in [0,2\pi]$.
By ex1.55, we can get the rotation index is$$R(m,n):=\frac{mn}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{m\cos(mt)\cos(nt)+n\sin(nt)\sin(mt)}{m^2\sin^2(mt)+n^2\cos^2(nt)}dt$$
I have used many ways to directly calculate this integral, but none of them have been effective.
However we have

(1) $R(m,n)=0$ if $m+n$ is odd (2) $R(km,kn)=kR(m,n)$

Hence we only need to show the case $m,n$ are coprime odd integers, which we have $R(m,n)=(-1)^{\frac{m-n}{2}}R(n,m)$  considering $t\mapsto t+\frac{\pi}{2}$ .
I find a lecture which says $R(m,n)=(-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$ (on page8) with no proof. I use a geometric explanation of the rotation index which counts how many times the tangent line to the curve is horizontal (with sign), and get:
$$R(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+\lfloor\frac{m(2k+1)}{2n}\rfloor}$$
Thus, get that $R(m,n)=(-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$ when $n=1,3,5,7$. Moreover, I use C++ to conclude that This equation still holds when $m,n \le 20000$ .
My questions are
(1) What is the rotation index of Lissajous curve?
(2) How to proof that $R(m,n)=(-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}$ always holds if $m,n$ are coprime odd integers?
(3) Some people say the Whitney formula can solve it, but I don't understand. Do you have a higher perspective on this question?
I have been confused by these questions recently and have not found any more useful information. I am very grateful if you have any helpful answers to this question.
